# Java setColor in render method not working

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to follow a simple 2D Game tutorial and setColor does not work. All that is outputted is a blank white screen. I have group members on windows and a blue screen is outputted whereas on macOS, that does not seem to be the case. Does anyone know what the issue may be? The following is my code:

```
package org.Display;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Screen extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    JFrame frame;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    int width;
    int height;

    public Screen(String title, int w, int h) {
        running = false;
        frame = new JFrame(title);

        width = w;
        height = h;

        // screen properties
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // closes the program when you click X
        frame.setSize(width, height); // set size of the screen
        frame.setResizable(false); // do not allow resizing
        frame.setVisible(true); // set the screen to visible
        frame.add(this);
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    // start game logic
    public void start() {
        running = true;

        // create our new thread
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }

    // stop game logic
    public void stop() {
        running = false;

        // stop our thread
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;

        while (running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1)
            {
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            Render();
            frames++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
            {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }

        stop();
    }

    // update screen
    private void tick() {

    }

    // paint onto window
    private void Render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy(); // makes transitions smoother

        // if haven't created BufferStrategy yet, create it
        if(bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(2);
            bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics(); // create graphics

        // test if Render works
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        bs.show();
        g.dispose(); // clear the screen
    }

    public void MainMenu() {
        // implement me
    }

    public void WiningScreen() {
        // implement me
    }

    public void GameScreen() {
        // implement me
    }

    public void GameOverScreen() {
        // implement me
    }
}
```

I have tried looking at other posts but none of them seem to have my exact problem.

Comment: When do you call `start`?  `Canvas` already has `getWidth/Height` methods, overriding them the way you have could have serious and unexpected consequences.  Instead, start by overriding `getPreferredSize` instead and then use `Canvas#getWidth` and `Canvas#getHeight` when you want to know the size

Comment: I would also recommend having a look at [the JavaDocs for `BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as it has an excellent example of how you should be using `BufferStrategy`.  Once I removed your `getWidth/Height` methods (and corrected the resulting compiler errors) and called `start` I was able to see the screen change color

Comment: @MadProgrammer start is called in my main class.

Comment: Well, it works for me - although it could be a threading issue, as the `Screen` could not be attached to a native peer before you start your `Thread`, but as I say, it works for me (with the noted modifications)

Comment: works for my group members as well. I am thinking that it has something to do with macOS as the ones on windows have it working while the members on macOS do not. Regardless, thank U for your help!

Comment: Nope - works fine for me on MacOS

Answer (score 1):

So, initially there are some ... concerns.

`Canvas` already has `getWidth/Height` methods, overriding them in the way you are could have adverse and unexpected results.  As general rule, you should avoid overriding them.  Instead, override `getPreferredSize` and return the "preferred" sizing hints you'd like used.

Use `getWidth/Height` to get the actual size of the component when you need to render to the `Canvas`'s surface.

It "could" be a threading issue, in order to create a `BufferStrategy`, the `Canvas` will need to be realised on the screen (ie attached to a native peer), before this, `Canvas` won't be able to create a `BufferStrategy` (`getBufferStrategy` will always return `null`), so you could be in a race condition.

Your `start`/`stop` methods are a little dubious - what happens if the `thread` is already running?

So, I modified your code, attempting to address some of the issues above and implemented a rendering cycle based on the example from the [`BufferStrategy` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and had no issues getting it to work.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Screen screen = new Screen();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(screen);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                screen.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Screen extends Canvas implements Runnable {
//        JFrame frame;
        private Thread thread;
        private volatile boolean running;
//        int width;
//        int height;

        public Screen() {
//            running = false;
//            frame = new JFrame(title);
//
//            width = w;
//            height = h;
//
//            // screen properties
//            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // closes the program when you click X
//            frame.setSize(width, height); // set size of the screen
//            frame.setResizable(false); // do not allow resizing
//            frame.setVisible(true); // set the screen to visible
//            frame.add(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        // start game logic
        public synchronized void start() {
            if (running) {
                return;
            }
            running = true;

            // create our new thread
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();

        }

        // stop game logic
        public synchronized void stop() {
            if (!running) {
                return;
            }
            running = false;

            // stop our thread
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
            double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
            double delta = 0;
            long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int updates = 0;
            int frames = 0;

            while (running) {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
                lastTime = now;
                while (delta >= 1) {
                    tick();
                    updates++;
                    delta--;
                }
                Render();
                frames++;
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                    timer += 1000;
                    System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
                    frames = 0;
                    updates = 0;
                }
            }
            // This is some what pointless
            stop();
        }

        // update screen
        private void tick() {

        }

        // paint onto window
        private void Render() {
            // makes transitions smoother
            BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

            // if haven't created BufferStrategy yet, create it
            if (bs == null) {
                this.createBufferStrategy(2);
                // It might still not be possible for the component
                // to create a buffer strategy yet, so we'll return
                // early and try again on the next loop
                return;
            }

            do {
                // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
                // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
                do {
                    // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
                    // to make sure the strategy is validated
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();

                    // Render to graphics
                    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
                    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                    // Dispose the graphics
                    g2d.dispose();

                    // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
                    // were restored
                } while (bs.contentsRestored());

                // Display the buffer
                bs.show();

                // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
            } while (bs.contentsLost());
        }

        public void MainMenu() {
            // implement me
        }

        public void WiningScreen() {
            // implement me
        }

        public void GameScreen() {
            // implement me
        }

        public void GameOverScreen() {
            // implement me
        }
    }
}
```